# Can you send JSON through a url?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I have a ruby hash where the keys are urls and the values are integers. I convert the hash to JSON and I'm wondering if I'll be able to send the JSON inside a url via an AJAX request and then pull that JSON from a params hash.

Also, I am going to be sending a JSONifyed ruby hash back to the client. If I have a success callback in my AJAX function where I receive the data in a `data` variable, how do I parse that JSON with JQuery?

Please let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: If you're doing AJAX requests why not POST it rather then sending the JSON as part of the URL...

Comment: @Endophage if I did that, then how would I access the JSON from the server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can with no problem. No manual encoding/decoding needed!

Your code would be like this:

```
var jsonParam = '{"name":"Edgar"}'; //Sample json param
$.ajax({
  ...  
  type: "get", //This sends in url
  data: {jsonParam: jsonParam}, //This will encode your json for url automatically
  dataType: "json", //With this the response will be automatically json-decoded!
  success: function(response){ //Assuming your server output was '{"lastName":"Villegas"}' as string
     alert(response.lastName);
  }
});
```

As you can see, no manual encoding/decoding was needed. Jquery handles it all!

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: If, for some reason, you need to encode/decode your json manually for url use javascript's `encodeURIComponent(string)` and `$.parseJSON(jsonString)` methods.

Comment: wait, so by specifying `dataType: "json"` I do not need to parse the JSON on the server? (ex. JSON.parse(json_here)). Also, if I decide to send it along as a POST request instead, how would I access the JSON on the server in ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass the json object as a get or post parameter.

In order to parse json string using Jquery you can use $.parseJSON.

Comment: I meant through the url itself. But if I do POST it and send it along in the `data` option, how would I access it from the controller?

Comment: It depends on your server side code. Eg in C# you can use Request[elementName], or in the controller action you can specify the exact parameter name it will automatically be populated when the action is executed.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli It will work, but is it a good practice to pass JSON object in get/query parameters?

Comment: @Nitin - Why not? Until and unless you are not sending a sensitive information.