# Potential problems with passing JSON in URL

Tags: json, url

I have a web page that is basically a form the user fills out.

I developed a C# VSTO Outlook 2010 Add-In that can create a JSON object based on the details of an appointment on a user's calendar. The JSON is then passed via the URL (in the Query String) to my web page. The object that is passed is used to automatically fill in the details on the web form. The web page is ASP.NET, although I don't think that's relevant.

This is the first time I've ever passed a JSON object in a URL. Are there any potential pitfalls I should watch out for? Anything that could go wrong? I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630427/can-you-send-json-through-a-url) that someone said you can pass JSON objects via URL with "no problems" but the question there was "can I do it?" rather than "what problems might I run into?"

Answer (score 2):

The most realistic problem (if you are not concerned with security) is the GET request size limitation. The IE, for example, have limitation of 2Kb for GET requests. So you could get into situation there your request will be trimmed.

And for the security issues mentioned, the GET requests are stored completely in browser history and thus can be potentially exposed to third-party.